# How to return the list value outside from mongoose find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using MongoDB database for tasks and im trying to find all the tasks with task_rating : "OK" and get the result into  one list and all tasks with task rating: "NOK" to second list and finaly render it to my HTML as two lists of information.

The problem is that whene I want to return the find results as list to outside value, it always returns me a weird object of Mongoose.

my code:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var nok_l = tasks.find({ task_rating: "NOK" }, (err, nokTasks) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            return nokTasks;
        }
    });
    var ok_l = tasks.find({ task_rating: "OK" }, (err, okTasks) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            return okTasks;
        }
    });

    console.log(ok_l);
    res.render("tasks", {
         ok_l: ok_l,
         nok_l: nok_l
     });
});
```

the result of the console.log print is werid object of Mongoose and not my list.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're printing the **Mongoose's promise object**, not the returned data, since the [Mongoose#find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) is assync.

There are many ways to handle over this scenario, but the most basic and "didactic" is return the data **only** when the promise is resolved:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    tasks.find({task_rating: "NOK"}, (err, nokTasks) => {

        if (!err) {
            tasks.find({task_rating: "OK"}, (err, okTasks) => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.render("tasks", {
                        ok_l: okTasks,
                        nok_l: nokTasks
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

But, this stack can be better structured if we store the promises references and resolve all using [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    let promises = [];

    promises.push(tasks.find({task_rating: "NOK"}).exec());
    promises.push(tasks.find({task_rating: "OK"}).exec());

    Promise.all(promises).then( (allTasks) => {
        // here it's necessary to handle the "OK" and "NOK" lists
        res.render("tasks", {
            list: allTasks
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you! its working!

There is a more "elegant" solution to handle over this scenario?
if I have a ten lists I have to make ten "finds" one inside another

Comment: hey @GuyCohen, I updated the answer with a better approach ;)